# Why is the showModalBottomSheet() function not working

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

Why is this code not working and the bottom sheet is not getting displayed. I've also retried running the code and still it doesn't work. I want to show a modal bottom sheet in flutter on a button click.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  void startInputAction(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return Container(
          height: 200,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Text("Something"),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Error Practice Bottom Sheet"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.purple,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text("Click here"),
                onPressed: () => startInputAction(context),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**MateriaApp** is at same level that's why you are getting this error.

Following code will solve your issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  void startInputAction(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) {
          return Container(
            height: 200,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Text("Something"),
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Error Practice Bottom Sheet"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.purple,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text("Click here"),
                onPressed: () => startInputAction(context))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked absolutely fine for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As @Viren suggested, you need to have a `MaterialApp` in your code.

Check the code below:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
    // add your material app here
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(), 
   ),
);

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  void startInputAction(BuildContext context){
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (_){
        return Container(
          height: 200,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Text("Something"),
        );
      }
    )
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Error Practice Bottom Sheet"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.purple,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Text("Click here"),
              onPressed: () => startInputAction(context)
            )
          ],
        ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. There's no need to add "hope this helps" to answers - technical writing is preferred here, and brevity is recommended. One presumes no-one posts an answer hoping that it doesn't help! `;-)`

Comment: Hi Halfer, thanks for the correction. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this example in the Flutter docs.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html

Your issue might have to do with you passing the same `BuildContext` from the `Scaffold`. You should at least add a `Builder` widget in the `body` parameter of `Scaffold` to get the appropriate context required for this widget.

Here's the code:

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  void startInputAction(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return Container(
          height: 200,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Text("Something"),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Error Practice Bottom Sheet"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        ),
        body: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.purple,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Text("Click here"),
                    onPressed: () => startInputAction(context),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't matter whether it was a StatefulWidget or a StatelessWidget, a Scaffold was declared in the `build` method and won't be able to show the modal bottom sheet.